# Python: How to use variables in a function in another function

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm creating a game in python so here's what I got...

```
def initGame():
    chip = int(input("How many chips would you like to start with? "))
    if chip<=0:
       print("Please input a number greater than 0")

    return chip
def displayPiles():
    print("It is your turn human.")
    print("Here are the piles:")
    pile1= print(chip)                     #What I originally had
    pile2= print(initGame())               #What I did after 
    print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
    print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
```

I read another similar question that said doing "pile1= print(initGame())" will return the variable "chip" in the "initGame()" function, but when I run it it looks like this

```
Welcome to the game of chips. I know you know the rules so let's go.
How many chips would you like to start with? 12
It is your turn human.
Here are the piles:
How many chips would you like to start with?
```

When it should look something like this

```
Welcome to the game of chips. I know you know the rules so let's go.
How many chips would you like to start with? 12
It is your turn human.
Here are the piles:
pile 1: 12
pile 2: 12
```

So my question is how do I get the "chip" variable to work in my other function?

EDIT:

```
 def initGame():
    chip = int(input("How many chips would you like to start with? "))
    if chip<=0:
        print("Please input a number greater than 0")

    return chip
def displayPiles():
    #chip= (trying to define chip from the initGame function so that I can set it to pile1,pile2)
    pile1= initGame()
    pile2= pile1
    print("It is your turn human.")
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    print("pile 1: "+ str(pile1))
    print("pile 2: "+ str(pile2))

    return pile1, pile2
def getHumanMove():
    x=int(input("Which pile would you like to take from?(1 or 2)"))
    y=int(input("How many would you like from pile "+ str(x)+ "? "))
    #if y>chip: (trying to recall chip from initGame) 
        print("pile " +str(x)+ " does not have that many chips. Try again.")
    elif y==0:
        print("You must take at least one chip. Try again.")
    else:
        print("That was a legal move. Thank You.")
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    pile1= initGame()
    pile2= initGame()
    if x == 1:
        pile1= initGame()- y
        print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
        print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
    elif x == 2:
        pile2= initGame()- y
        print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
        print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
        return pile1, pile2

def getCompMove(getHumanMove):
    print("Now it's my turn.")
    #x= (Trying to recall the x,y values from the function getHumanMove)
    #y= 
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        if x==1:
            print("I, the champion chips computer will take "+str(y)+ " chips from pile 2")
            pile2= pile2 - y
        elif x==2:
            print("I, the champion chips computer will take "+str(y)+ " chips from pile 1")
            pile1= pile1 - y
        if pile1==0 and pile2==0:
            finished= True
            print("The game is over because I took the last chip.")
            print("Thanks for playing. Let's wager next time.")        
    return pile1,pile2


#######################################################################
#Main

print("Welcome to the game of chips. I know you know the rules so let's go.")

#chips= initGame()

piles = displayPiles()

move= getHumanMove()

comp= getCompMove()

print(move)
```

Comment: You should probably use a [**class**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're using a print statement with a nested call to initGame() function and you're assuming that the print() will return something to the variables pile1 and pile2.

Try this:

```
def initGame():
    chip = int(input("How many chips would you like to start with? "))
    if chip<=0:
       print("Please input a number greater than 0")

    return chip

def displayPiles():
    print("It is your turn human.")
    print("Here are the piles:")
    pile2 = initGame()                  # Changed here
    print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
```

Edit #1 (in reply to comments):

In order to test this portion of code (only), create a new .py file and put the following into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def initGame():
    chip = int(input("How many chips would you like to start with? "))
    if chip<=0:
       print("Please input a number greater than 0")

    return chip

def displayPiles():
    print("It is your turn human.")
    print("Here are the piles:")
    pile2 = initGame()                  # Changed here
    print "pile 2:", str(pile2)

displayPiles()
```

Does this behave as expected?

Edit #2 (in reply to new comments):

```
def initGame():
    chip = int(input("How many chips would you like to start with? "))
    if chip<=0:
        print("Please input a number greater than 0")

    return chip
def displayPiles():
    print("It is your turn human.")
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    pile1= initGame()
    pile2= initGame()
    print("pile 1: " + str(pile1))       # Changed here
    print("pile 2: " + str(pile2))       # Changed here

    return pile1, pile2

def getHumanMove():
    x=int(input("Which pile would you like to take from?(1 or 2)"))
    y=int(input("How many would you like from pile " + str(x) + "? "))   # Changed here

    return x,y


#######################################################################
#Main

print("Welcome to the game of chips. I know you know the rules so let's go.")

#chips= initGame()            # Commented this

piles = displayPiles()

move= getHumanMove()

print move                    # Added this
```

You should not call the initGame() function (the one that i've commented), as it's already called inside displayPiles(). You should also rename it to initPile().

Comment: Still seems like it's doing the same thing

Comment: That's weird. I suspected that the next question would be why the print statement isn't working as expected (since you're passing a tuple to it)... but the same behavior after that change is something that I wouldn't expect. Are you sure you've exactly what I've post? Are you calling displayPiles() directly? Do you have any other code that can be causing any other kind of trouble?

Comment: It works with 1 pile but when I do two piles, it doesn't return anything. @threadp

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current code with two piles?

Comment: Please check the Edit #2. Tell me if you understand the changes or if you need further explanation.

Comment: Ohh. I see, it works but when running it it outputs "How many chips would you like to start with?" twice in a row, is this because I'm calling it twice?

Comment: That's correct. Because you're initializing pile1 and pile2 with initGame(), the code of initGame() will be executed as many times you call it.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late responses, I've been pretty busy this week but if you're still willing to help, I've changed some things. But I'm still having troubles with my original question. So pile 1 and pile 2 are two different piles, I can't set both equal to "initGame()" or else it would ask "How many chips do you want to start out with" twice. I also can't use a global function. Although I read that global functions would make this worse. I've added a comment to the lines where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The return from a print is None you need to store the value and print it seperately, i.e.:

Instead of:

```
pile2= print(initGame())
```

Try:

```
pile2 = initGame()
print(pile2)
```